# override omniauth github callback uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, oauth, omniauth

I recently deployed a couple of rails app servers behind elastic load balancer using the wizard in elastic beanstalk. I set up SSL and tested to ensure the app routes return data, they do, and the green checkmark shows up showing SSL is installed. Sweet!

I have been previously using single app servers. Unfortunately, now that I have several behind elastic load balancer, it seems like i have broken my github oauth integration via omniauth. The error I'm getting is a redirect uri mismatch. The github app is set up to call back to https://my-load-balancer.com, but the oauth request being sent to github:

GET /login/oauth/authorize?

has a param redirect_uri which is filled out automatically by omniauth with https://my-app-server-number-one.com/callback-slug-here. This is a mismatch to the load balancer address. Github's documentation suggests to remove the redirect_uri parameter from the request, and it will automatically send to the registered callback URI instead of the currently erroneous uri in the query string.

I checked the omniauth and omniauth-github docs but wasn't able to find a great explanation of configuration. is it possible to override this parameter?

Thanks!